# Google Speech Api Credential Error with Raspbian (Raspberry pi)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian, google-speech-api

i want to make a speech to text program so i used Google Speech Api.
When i launched the code on my pc it works, but on raspberry pi it doesnt. Probably it is about Credential, but i tried so many things. For example:
i add GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with this command:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

but it still creates error [image]

i dont know what should i do.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to restart your terminal for the commands in .bashrc to take effect. If you don't want to restart the terminal, type

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="<creds>"`

Comment: I tried your advice, but nothing changes. I update to question, i added my bashrc echo.

Comment: Can you go back to your PC and echo the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable?